# Codeigniter active record class join two mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Just want to get **user_id** and **review_text** values from table **reviews**, select **name** and **city** from table **users** where **id=user_id** and then return **review_text, username** and **city** to controller. Please help me.

```
public function did_get_reviews($item_id){

    $this->db->select('user_id','review_text');
    $this->db->from('reviews');   
    $this->db->where('post_id', $item_id);

    $user_id = 'user_id' //??

    $this->db->select('name','city');
    $this->db->from('users');   
    $this->db->where('id', $user_id);

    $query = $this->db->get('review_text','username','city'); //??

    if ($query && $query->num_rows() >= 1){
    return $query->result();
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
   }
```

**Update 1:**
I just tried to join tables but it returns the values for **review_text** only but I also want to get values for **name** and **city**. Please check the code below:

```
public function did_get_reviews($item_id){

    $this->db->select('reviews.review_text','users.name','users.city');
    $this->db->from('reviews','users');   
    $this->db->where('reviews.post_id', $item_id);
    $this->db->join('users','reviews.user_id = users.user_id');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query && $query->num_rows() >= 1){
    return $query->result();
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Can you explain more about your update code issue?

Comment: It returns the values for **review_text** only but I also want to get values for **name** and **city**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need to use **join** query in SQL. if you use this code you can access to what you want

```
$result = $this->db->select('review, username, city')
            ->from('reviews')
            ->join('city', 'city.user_id = review.user_id')
            ->get();
print_r($result);
```

for more information about how you can write join query(left, inner or right) in codeigniter you can see this [link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

i hope that this code solve your problem

---

**UPDATE**

in your new question. your code have a little buggy. you need to write your select in this way

```
public function did_get_reviews($item_id){

    $this->db->select('reviews.review_text,users.name,users.city')
             ->from('reviews','users')   
             ->where('reviews.post_id', $item_id)
             ->join('users','reviews.user_id = users.user_id');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query && $query->num_rows() >= 1){
    return $query->result();
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
   }
```

in codeigniter select Active record; any column name separate with each other by `,` only (not by `'` and `,`)

**in codeigniter [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select) wrote that**

> Permits you to write the SELECT portion of your query:
>
> $this->db->select('title, content, date');
>
> $query = $this->db->get('mytable');
>
> // Produces: SELECT title, content, date FROM mytable

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please check the update of my question.

Comment: You are GREAT! It returns all the values now. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value for `user_id` using:

```
$this->db->select('user_id','review_text');
$this->db->from('reviews');   
$this->db->where('post_id', $item_id);
$result = $this->db->get();
print_r($result);
```

use the same `$this->db->get();` to get the values of the second query as well. Once you get the values inside a variable you can iterate it. Something like:

```
foreach ($result->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->name;
    echo $row->city;
}
```